# Are the events shown as Ten Rings influencing history meant to map to historical events?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*, at the beginning of the film, when the Ten Rings organization is being described, it is indicated that they have shaped history throughout the ages, and two scenes are shown with seeming terrorist or assassination tactics, first a building explosion (if I were to guess, it looked like a British embassy) and then some people being gunned down in a Middle East setting from atop a wall. Are these intended to match up to non-MCU historical assassinations or bombings, thereby explaining how these events happened in the fictional context?

Comment: I had a look at the relevant section of the movie in the commentary available on Disney Plus, but nothing helpful there. :-/

Answer (score 5):

### There's not much information on this out there

The historical scenes you mention are ignored by the [Director's Commentary](https://www.disneyplus.com/en-gb/video/98cdfe57-59c3-47ee-af36-e2eadaf7b4e8), [New Rockstars' breakdown](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?view=detail&mid=8DDE69876B219FD231548DDE69876B219FD23154&q=youtube%20ten%20rings&shtp=GetUrl&shid=ffa0b1c9-71af-4864-9a25-7879b63530b1&shtk=U0hBTkcgQ0hJIFBPU1QgQ1JFRElUIFNDRU5FUyAmIEVuZGluZyBFeHBsYWluZWQhIChTUE9JTEVSUyk%3D&shdk=U2hhbmctQ2hpIEVuZC1DcmVkaXQgc2NlbmVzIGJyZWFrZG93biBcdTAwMjYgZmluYWwgc2NlbmUgZXhwbGFpbmVkISBDbGljayBodHRwOi8vdmVzc2kuY29tL25ld3JvY2tzdGFycyBhbmQgdXNlIGNvZGUgTkVXUk9DS1NUQVJTIHRvIGdldCAkMjUgb2ZmIG9mIHlvdXIgVmVzc2kgc2hvZXMuIEZyZWUgc2hpcHBpbmcgdG8gQ0EsIFVTLCBBVVMsIE5aLCBKUCwgVFcsIEtSLCBTR1AgU3BvaWxlcnMgYWhlYWQhIENoZWNrIG91dCBvdXIgc3dlZXQsIHN3ZWV0IG1lcmNoISBodHRwOi8vd3d3Lm5ld3JvY2tzdGFyc21lcmNoLmNvbSBTdWJzY3JpYmU6IGh0dHA6Ly9iaXQubHkvU3ViTmV3Um9ja3N0YXJzIC4uLg%3D%3D&shhk=Iy6NM5fZ55uRUdZq%2FjWnx6I%2BbhjJLSd1XawH%2F2TaceA%3D&form=VDSHOT&shth=OVP.f9c38IZMJvY92KD1Fnsi3gEsCo) and [Looper's breakdown](https://youtu.be/XyoNwvMZrrk). The usually excellent MCU wikia has [stub entries](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ten_Rings_(Organization)#Assassination_of_British_Official).

All we have is narrated by the audio description:

**A snowy battle scene**

> The warrior uses his rings to thwart enemies with their force then whips them at a stagecoach which spills riches as it tumbles.

**Centuries later, at a castle**

> Assassins from the Ten Rings toss a royal general off a castle wall

**Bombing an embassy-style building**

> In England, a terrorist sets off an explosion

**Sniping in a jungle**

> Now an assassin mows down several men with a machine gun

These scenes are perhaps deliberately vague and allusive, suggesting that the Ten Rings have been involved in 'changing history' without being too explicit as to exactly how.

Answer (score -2):

No,  what the movie was trying to show was how The Ten Organizations has been influencing history for a long time and how they have gained the power they now had. It could be said that these were just random bombings or assassinations but the actual motive of the scene was just to show how powerful the Organization is and how they can assassinate anybody they want to. There has been no links of these events shown in the movie to real world incidents.

Plus dozens of assassination, bombings and terrorist attacks take place every year so linking these scenes to one of them would be hard.

As you mentioned a bombing and an assassination it is in fact the assassination of a British official but the bombing has not been specified [here](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ten_Rings_(Organization)):

[image: Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki]

Comment: Where is this image sourced from?

Comment: Do you have any source for this, or is it just your own speculation?

Comment: @Jontia: It seems to be a screenshot of the wiki entry, so unfortunately, it seems unsourced.